# Switch statement that maps through array gives unreachable code warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this will probably be a very easy solution that I am missing, but hoping someone could help.

I am looping through an array and trying to figure out the length of it, and return different values depending on the length. Then I map through it and hopefully return the value depending on the amount. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Thank you all for your comments. What I intend to do with the switch statement result is determine a grid size depending on the getGridPercentages array value. So if it is '4' it would return '25% 25% 25% 25%'.

I am then using the value in a styled component using CSS grid's grid-template-columns:

```js
const ContainerWrapper = styled.div `
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: ${op}; //Value of grid here
grid-gap: 10px;
`;
```

```js
const getGridPercentages = [
    {
        Text: '1'
    },
    {
        Text: '2'
    },
    {
        Text: '3'
    },
    {
        Text: '4'
    }
]

let op = getGridPercentages.map(function(item) {
    const getAmount = item.Text;
    switch(getAmount) {
        case '1':
            return '100%'
        case '2':
            return '50% 50%'
        case '3':
            return '33% 33% 33%'
        case '4':
            return '25% 25% 25% 25%'
        default: 
            return 1            
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the expected result from the above? why `map` without using the result?

Comment: Where is the warning?

Comment: In fact,if you use `return` then `break` is redundant

Comment: `getAmount` will always be 1.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: What's returning the warning here - TypeScript? A linter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should make these changes**

1. item.Text.length will always return 1 as you're trying to find length of single character.
2. No need of break statement after return statement.(This is what unreachable code looks like)

```js
const getGridPercentages = [
    {
        Text: '1'
    },
    {
        Text: '2'
    },
    {
        Text: '3'
    },
    {
        Text: '4'
    }
]

let op = getGridPercentages.map(function(item) {
    const getAmount = item.Text;
    
    switch(getAmount) {
        case '1':
            return '100%'
        case '2':
            return '50% 50%'
        case '3':
            return '33% 33% 33%'
        case '4':
            return '25% 25% 25% 25%'
        default: 
            return 1            
    }
});

console.log(op);
```

**Update:** As you asked in comments you want based on number of elements which is in complete contrary of what question is saying.

```js
const getGridPercentages = [
    {
        Text: '1'
    },
    {
        Text: '2'
    },
    {
        Text: '3'
    },
    {
        Text: '4'
    }
]

function getGridSize(arr){
  switch(arr.length) {
        case 1:
            return '100%'
        case 2:
            return '50% 50%'
        case 3:
            return '33% 33% 33%'
        case 4:
            return '25% 25% 25% 25%'
        default: 
            return 1            
    }

}

console.log(getGridSize(getGridPercentages))
```

Comment: Hey @Code Maniac, first of all thank you very much for your answer, and sorry for the late response!

I have a quick question about something, I am basically trying to use the switch statement to determine the grid size of the component (e.g. 4 = 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%)

When i copy your code, it actually returns everything at the minute? Do you know what I need to do to just return the correct amount?

Comment: @marko without seeing code how you're using i can be sure.will you update code or a link than i can tell better.

Comment: Hey! I've just updated with a bit more information, using your code above as my starting point. Thanks!!!

Comment: @marko since we are having a array as input and return value is also.You want single value at a time ?

Comment: Yes please! In this case, we would return '25% 25% 25% 25%' as there is 4 Text values in the getGridPercentages array

Comment: What do you mean by 4 text values in array ? you want to have value base on the elements in array ?

Comment: Sorry if i am being confusing here.

Currently there are 4 Text values in the array

{
    Text: '1'
},
{
    Text: '2'
},
{
     Text: '3'
},
{
     Text: '4'
}

If there are 4 Text values returned in the array, it will then return 25%, 25%, 25%, 25% that is in the switch statement under case '4' - does that make sense?

Thanks

Comment: @marko than mate this is completely misleading what you asked in your question and what you're trying to achieve. Anyway will help you

Comment: Sorry about the confusion here @Code Maniac, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @marko updated the answer.if you like you don't forget to mark it as right answer :p. And be clear about your question that will help you get better and good answers. Always happy to help mate :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very very much for your help!!!! Marked as correct answer, thank you so much @Code Maniac!!!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

One, you don't need a `break` statement after a `return`. That's what's triggering the error in the console.

Two, you are switching on the length of each `Text` field. Text's length is always one. Therefore any other branches in your switch statement are also unreachable code.

Answer (score -1):

You are using switch statement and when the condition match you are returning a value so there is no need for using break; keyword after return. Your switch statement should looks like:

```
switch(getAmount) {
    case 1:
        return '100%'
    case 2:
        return '50% 50%'
    case 3:
        return '33% 33% 33%'
    case 4:
        return '25% 25% 25% 25%'
    default: 
        return 1            
    }
```

EDIT:
and also you are getting the length of every Text string which will be in your case every time 1.

Comment: `break` does not hurt. i mean it is not the problem.

Comment: actually it can because every break; keyword is unreachable code (after return keyword) in this example.

Comment: it is something that browser doesn't know... what strings with what length does the list contain. So the length of the every string can differ by string content itself...

Comment: I don't think there's any mainstream code analyzer that's advanced enough to analyze and derive all potential input values, so it can't possibly determine that any particular branch will never be reached. @sebinq is right, the warning doesn't come from an unreachable branch but from the `break` statements that can never be reached because the function returns just before.

Comment: @Lennholm there are some circumstances where TypeScript can detect unreachable switch cases, also tests that use instrumentation + fuzzing. But you are right, the issue here is with the `breaks` coming after `returns`.